# Dynamically fetch columns as JSON in oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I have to get some columns as is and some columns from a query as JSON document. The as is column names are known to me but rest are dynamic columns so there are not known beforehand.

Below is the query like

```
select col1,col2,col3,
       sum(col4) as col4,
       sum(col5) as col5
from my_table
group by col1,col2,col3;
```

here col4,col5 names are unknown to me as they are been fetched dynamically.

Suppost my_table data looks like

[image]

The expected result is like below

[image]

I tried

```
select JSON_OBJECT(*) from
(
select col1,col2,col3,
       sum(col4) as col4,
       sum(col5) as col5
from my_table
group by col1,col2,col3
);
```

But obviously it does not yield expected output.
I'm on 19c DB version 19.17
Any help or suggestion would be great help!

Comment: use can use Dot Notation if you have a CHECK IS_JSON constraint on your JSON_DOC_DATA column, so querying col4 becomes more or less json_doc_data.col4

Comment: What's the input dataset? What do you mean by `col4` or `col5` which are nested within `sum()`?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Please check edited question with input dataset.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Yes i tried, it surely works but I wanted to know if oracle JSON supports dynamic column conversion either ways meaning converting columns to JSON and JSON back to columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may achieve this by using [Polymorphic Table Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_TF.html) available since 18c.

Define the function that will project only specific columns and serialize others into JSON. An implementation is below.

1. PTF package (function implementation).

> ```
> create package pkg_jsonify as
>   /*Package to implement PTF.
>   Functions below implement the API
>   described in the DBMS_TF package*/
>
>   function describe(
>     tab in out dbms_tf.table_t,
>     keep_cols in dbms_tf.columns_t
>   ) return dbms_tf.describe_t
>   ;
>   
>   procedure fetch_rows;
> end pkg_jsonify;
> /
> ```

> ```
> create package body pkg_jsonify as
>
>   function describe(
>     tab in out dbms_tf.table_t,
>     keep_cols in dbms_tf.columns_t
>   ) return dbms_tf.describe_t
>   as
>     add_cols dbms_tf.columns_new_t;
>     new_col_cnt pls_integer := 0;
>   begin
>     for i in 1..tab.column.count loop
>       /*Initially remove column from the output*/
>       tab.column(i).pass_through := FALSE;
>       /*and keep it in the row processing (to be available for serialization*/
>       tab.column(i).for_read := TRUE;
>       for j in 1..keep_cols.count loop
>         /*If column is in a projection list, then remove it
>         from processing and pass it as is*/
>         if tab.column(i).description.name = keep_cols(j)
>           then
>             tab.column(i).pass_through := TRUE;
>             /*Skip column in the row processing (JSON serialization)*/
>             tab.column(i).for_read := FALSE;
>         end if;
>       end loop;
>     end loop;
>
>     /*Define new output column*/
>     add_cols := dbms_tf.columns_new_t(
>       1 => dbms_tf.column_metadata_t(
>         name => 'JSON_DOC_DATA',
>         type => dbms_tf.type_clob
>       )
>     );
>     
>     /*Return the list of new cols*/
>     return dbms_tf.describe_t(
>       new_columns => add_cols
>     );
>   end;
>   
>   procedure fetch_rows
>   /*Process rowset and serialize cols*/
>   as
>     rowset dbms_tf.row_set_t;
>     num_rows pls_integer;
>     new_col dbms_tf.tab_clob_t;
>   begin
>     /*Get rows*/
>     dbms_tf.get_row_set(
>       rowset => rowset,
>       row_count => num_rows
>     );
>     
>     for rn in 1..num_rows loop
>       /*Calculate new column value in the same row*/
>       new_col(rn) := dbms_tf.row_to_char(
>         rowset => rowset,
>         rid => rn,
>         format => dbms_tf.FORMAT_JSON
>       );
>     end loop;
>     
>     /*Put column to output*/
>     dbms_tf.put_col(
>       columnid => 1,
>       collection => new_col
>     );
>
>   end;
> end pkg_jsonify;
> /
> ```

2. PTF function definition based on the package.

> ```
> create function f_cols_to_json(tab in table, cols in columns)
> /*Function to serialize into JSON using PTF*/
> return table pipelined
> row polymorphic using pkg_jsonify;
> /
> ```

3. Demo.

> ```
> create table sample_tab
> as
> select
>   trunc(level/10) as id
>   , mod(level, 3) as id2
>   , level as val1
>   , level * level as val2
> from dual
> connect by level < 40
> ```

> ```
> with prep as (
>   select
>     id
>     , id2
>     , sum(val1) as val1_sum
>     , max(val2) as val2_max
>   from sample_tab
>   
>   group by
>     id
>     , id2
> )
> select *
> from table(f_cols_to_json(prep, columns(id, id2)))
> ```

| ID | ID2 | JSON_DOC_DATA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | {"VAL1_SUM":12, "VAL2_MAX":49} |
| 0 | 2 | {"VAL1_SUM":15, "VAL2_MAX":64} |
| 0 | 0 | {"VAL1_SUM":18, "VAL2_MAX":81} |
| 1 | 1 | {"VAL1_SUM":58, "VAL2_MAX":361} |
| 1 | 2 | {"VAL1_SUM":42, "VAL2_MAX":289} |
| 1 | 0 | {"VAL1_SUM":45, "VAL2_MAX":324} |
| 2 | 2 | {"VAL1_SUM":98, "VAL2_MAX":841} |
| 2 | 0 | {"VAL1_SUM":72, "VAL2_MAX":729} |
| 2 | 1 | {"VAL1_SUM":75, "VAL2_MAX":784} |
| 3 | 0 | {"VAL1_SUM":138, "VAL2_MAX":1521} |
| 3 | 1 | {"VAL1_SUM":102, "VAL2_MAX":1369} |
| 3 | 2 | {"VAL1_SUM":105, "VAL2_MAX":1444} |

> ```
> with prep as (
>   select
>     id
>     , id2
>     , sum(val1) as val1_sum
>     , max(val2) as val2_max
>   from sample_tab
>   group by
>     id
>     , id2
> )
> select *
> from table(f_cols_to_json(prep, columns(id)))
> ```

| ID | JSON_DOC_DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {"ID2":1, "VAL1_SUM":12, "VAL2_MAX":49} |
| 0 | {"ID2":2, "VAL1_SUM":15, "VAL2_MAX":64} |
| 0 | {"ID2":0, "VAL1_SUM":18, "VAL2_MAX":81} |
| 1 | {"ID2":1, "VAL1_SUM":58, "VAL2_MAX":361} |
| 1 | {"ID2":2, "VAL1_SUM":42, "VAL2_MAX":289} |
| 1 | {"ID2":0, "VAL1_SUM":45, "VAL2_MAX":324} |
| 2 | {"ID2":2, "VAL1_SUM":98, "VAL2_MAX":841} |
| 2 | {"ID2":0, "VAL1_SUM":72, "VAL2_MAX":729} |
| 2 | {"ID2":1, "VAL1_SUM":75, "VAL2_MAX":784} |
| 3 | {"ID2":0, "VAL1_SUM":138, "VAL2_MAX":1521} |
| 3 | {"ID2":1, "VAL1_SUM":102, "VAL2_MAX":1369} |
| 3 | {"ID2":2, "VAL1_SUM":105, "VAL2_MAX":1444} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TQAVDv2b)

Answer (score 3):

It's kinda hacky, but you could:

- Use `json_object(*)` to convert the whole row to `json`
- Pass the result of this [`json_transform`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/oracle-sql-function-json_transform.html)*, which you can use to remove unwanted attributes

So you could do something like:

```
with rws as (
  select mod ( level, 2 ) col1, mod ( level, 3 ) col2, 
         level col3, level col4
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 10
), grps as (
  select col1,col2,
         sum(col3) as col3,
         sum(col4) as col4
  from   rws
  group by col1,col2
)
select col1,col2,
       json_transform ( 
         json_object(*),
         remove '$.COL1',
         remove '$.COL2' 
       ) json_data
from   grps;

      COL1       COL2 JSON_DATA                     
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         1          1 {"COL3":8,"COL4":8}           
         0          2 {"COL3":10,"COL4":10}         
         1          0 {"COL3":12,"COL4":12}         
         0          1 {"COL3":14,"COL4":14}         
         1          2 {"COL3":5,"COL4":5}           
         0          0 {"COL3":6,"COL4":6}
```

- `json_transform` is a 21c feature that's been backported to 19c in 19.10.

Comment: Thanks I can work with this.. Is there any way I can convert JSON_DATA column back to Relational rows and columns..I see json_table supports this but I have to specify the column name in PATH which I can't do.

Comment: Not that I know of automatically like `json_object(*)`. Though this does beg the question - why on earth are you converting it to JSON in the first place if you want it relationally in the end?!

Comment: Firstly, I converted it to JSON for storage purpose meaning I can have any number of dynamic columns since its unknown I can't represent it as relational column in the table. Secondly, for further processing of these dynamic columns I want to represent them as relational columns to fetch them easily. Hope I'm able to stand my point.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do; the whole approach seems flawed to me though. I don't understand the use case for "storing dynamic columns as JSON"